# Update Model against change in table in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to update the models in MVC if the tables in the database change?

If, for example, a column is added to a table in the database, can I update the corresponding model? I am talking about a situation when the application is live ...

Comment: This could be possible if you use Reflection to create your `Model` objects and also to populate them.

Comment: Is there no other way?can you provide me with a link with a simple example??

Comment: Unforunately not, I'm not that familiar with Reflection. I hope someone else comes up with an example.

Comment: @AlexBarac : Wouldn't that be possible using an ORM like Entity Framework where the model would change according to the schema in DB? I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Even if you could automate the process of adding model properties to reflect new database table fields, the application would need to be recompiled so its never going to work _...when the application is live_

Comment: so reflection is the only process??